# If statement in batch file - user chooses option

Tags: windows, if-statement, batch-file

New to batch/sql files. Thanks for you help.

What im trying to do:

- user picks option 1, runs my sql file.
- user picks 2, exits program.
- user enters nothing or invalid option, ECHO "invalid option".

Problem: anything I type will exit my program. What am I doing wrong?

```
ECHO 1 - Show Report
ECHO 2 - Exit

SET choice=""
SET /P input=Your choice: 
IF "%input%"=="1" (
    GOTO :sql file
) ELSE (
    IF "%input%"=="2" (
    GOTO :Exit
    )
) ELSE (
    IF "%input%"=="" (
    ECHO Invalid option chosen.
    )
)
PAUSE
```

Comment: Your variable name is `choice` not `input`. You may want to consider using the `CHOICE` command instead of `SET /P`.

Comment: sorry, got rid of the "choice" variable and changed to input.

Comment: The syntax of the `IF..ELSE` is not correct.  You cannot have multiple `ELSE` conditions linked to a single `IF`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `choice` command, its instructions are available by entering `choice /?` at the Command Prompt.

```batch-file
@ECHO OFF
ECHO 1 - Show Report
ECHO 2 - Exit
CHOICE /C 12 /M "Your choice"
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO :EOF
REM This line is your SQL report code
PAUSE
```

If you still wanted to use, what in your case I believe is the wrong `Set /P` input method, then something like this should be relatively robust, given that your end user is free to enter whatever they like as input, mischievous or harmful intent included:

```batch-file
@ECHO OFF
ECHO 1 - Show Report
ECHO 2 - Exit
:GETInput
SET "input="
SET /P "input=Your choice: "
2>&1 SET input | FINDSTR /XR "input=[12]" 1>NUL || (
    ECHO Invalid option chosen
    GOTO GETInput
)
IF %input% EQU 2 GOTO :EOF
REM This line is your SQL report code
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one extract closing bracket `[Line #12]` inside nested `if..else`. Also, as far as i know, your label `:sql file` should not contain space and you must declare it inside the batch file (Same for label `:Exit`)

I did few changes in your code to make it work

```
@echo off

:Main
cls
ECHO 1 - Show Report
ECHO 2 - Exit

SET choice=""
SET /P input=Your choice: 
IF "%input%"=="1" (
    GOTO :SQLReport
) ELSE IF "%input%"=="2" (
    GOTO :EOF
) ELSE (
    ECHO.
    ECHO Invalid option chosen.
    pause
    GOTO :Main
)

:SQLReport
ECHO.
ECHO Running SQL Report...
GOTO :EOF

:EOF
```